# Flex: Programmatically determine value selected from MultiSelectComboBox

Tags: apache-flex

I am new to Flex and want to programmatically determine the value selected from a MultiSelectComboBox. The code is as follows:

```
<columns: ExtendedDataGridColumn
                    width="50" dataField="department" 
                    filterComboBoxBuildFromGrid="false"
                    filterComboBoxDataField="label"
                    filterComboBoxDataProvider="{deptCollection}"
                    filterControl="MultiSelectComboBox"
                    filterOperation="Equals"
                    sortable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to check the selected value (or values), use the `selectedItems` property:

```
private function querySelections() {
    foreach (var item:* in multiComboBox) {
        trace(item.id);
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll need to make sure that you can get a reference to the MultiSelectComboBox to the code that wants to read it.  If it's defined inside an ItemRenderer, you'll need to make sure to expose it to the calling code.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply . How do I get a reference to the multiselectcombobox ? If I define an id attribute in the extendedatagridcolumn, "id" will refer to it right ? I am not using a custom defined multicombobox. Not sure how I can get a reference for it .

Comment: Good question.  Where is your multiselectcombobox defined?

Comment: I use the multicombobox feature by using the filterControl feature in the extended advanced data grid as you can see from the code below. Not sure how I can get a reference to the combobox ? Do I sound right ?